# Efficient multidimensional dynamic time warping implementation

Tags: r, performance, image-processing, distance

Here's how the literature explains how to compute multidimensional dynamic time warping of two time series:

```
 library(dtw)
 x<- cbind(1:10,1)
 y<- cbind(11:15,2)
 cxdist <-dist(x,y,method="euclidean")
 dtw(cxdist)$distance
```

In fact it first computes the cross distance matrix and then use it as input in the dtw function.

I'd like to use multidimensional dynamic time warping in image classification with quite large images. 
Image values are stored in a data frame that could look like this:

```
 inDf <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 6))
 colnames(inDf) <- c('var1t1','var2t1','var1t2','var2t2','var1t3','var2t3')
```

In this example, there are two variables (var1 and var2) observed three times.

The question is how to get the dtw distance matrix with the as much efficiency as possible regarding computing intensity?

Here are some thoughts:
- iterate through each values of the input image matrices, reshape the vectors to matrices in order to be able to compute the cross distances and then compute the dtw distance and store it in a dedicated matrix.
This is certainly the most computing intensive solution

Comment: So, you need efficient computation of distance matrix (euclidean) between var1 and var2 (both are 3-dimensional arrays of the same length)? I.e. between `x <- inDf[,c("var1t1","var1t2","var1t3")]` and `y <- inDf[,c("var2t1","var2t2","var2t3")]`?

Comment: Can you clarify how `inDf` relates to your first example?  Is `var1t1` `x`, and `var2t1` `y`, and then repeated again for the other two time periods?  Are you looking to calculate the `dtw` distance for each pair of variables at each time period?  And how do these things relate to images?  Aside, it looks like `dtw` calculates the `dist` itself, so you don't need to that step.

Comment: The difference between the first and the second example is the number of variables measured for each sample. In the first,  x and y are both time-series of the same unique variable over time. In the second, each x is characterized by two variables, two time series. Hope it's clearer

Comment: In second example, what are the dimensions of `cxdist`? As far as I understand they should be `10x10`. Thus, we are calculating pairwise distances between 10 3-dimensional points in `var1` and 10 3-dimensional points in `var2`. Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with intensive computations always makes sense to consider `Rcpp` package. If you want to get distance matrix with euclidean distances faster, you can implement corresponding `Rcpp` function:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

# Rcpp function for euclidean distance
fastdist <- cxxfunction(signature(x="matrix", y="matrix"), plugin="Rcpp",
body='
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix dx(x);
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix dy(y);

  const int N = dx.nrow();
  const int M = dy.nrow();

  Rcpp::NumericMatrix res(N, M);

  for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
      res(i,j) = sqrt(sum((dx(i,_)-dy(j,_))*(dx(i,_)-dy(j,_))));
    }
  }

  return res;
')
```

It uses `Rcpp` syntactic `sugar` in order to make code more compact and readable. However, sometimes it's better having wrapper function for checking types, coercing, etc. It's not necessary - you can call `fastdist` directly. But, anyway, wrapper can look like this:

```
# Wrapper R function
fast.dist <- function(x, y){
  stopifnot(class(x) %in% c("data.frame","matrix") &
            class(y) %in% c("data.frame","matrix") &
            ncol(x)==ncol(y))

  fastdist(as.matrix(x), as.matrix(y))
}
```

Now we can turn to literature example.

```
library(dtw)

# EXAMPLE 1
x<- cbind(1:10,1)
y<- cbind(11:15,2)
# Check results
all.equal(fast.dist(x,y), dist(x,y,method="euclidean"), check.attributes=F)
# [1] "target is matrix, current is crossdist"
all.equal(fast.dist(x,y), matrix(dist(x,y,method="euclidean"), ncol=nrow(y)))
# [1] TRUE
```

Note, that `dist` returns result of class `crossdist`. So, for comparison it should be coerced to `matrix`.

And now your primary question - we're generating data first:

```
# EXAMPLE 2
set.seed(1234)
N <- 100
inDf <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(6*N), ncol = 6))
colnames(inDf) <- c('var1t1','var2t1','var1t2','var2t2','var1t3','var2t3')

# Extracting variables
var1 <- inDf[,c("var1t1","var1t2","var1t3")]
var2 <- inDf[,c("var2t1","var2t2","var2t3")]
```

I'm not completely sure about your data structure, but in any case you can always prepare variables according to your needs.

Comparison and benchmarking:

```
library(rbenchmark)

all.equal(fast.dist(var1,var2), matrix(dist(var1,var2), ncol=N))
# [1] TRUE
benchmark(fast.dist(var1,var2), dist(var1,var2), order="relative")[,1:4]
#                    test replications elapsed relative
# 1 fast.dist(var1, var2)          100   0.081    1.000
# 2      dist(var1, var2)          100   0.246    3.037
```

`fast.dist` is roughly 3 times faster than `dist` in this case. However, while `N` is growing the relative speed-up will go down.

Also note, as were mentioned in comments, `dtw` can compute distance matrix by itself. Nevertheless, it's more efficient to have distance matrix precomputed. See quick test below:

```
cxdist <- fast.dist(var1,var2)
benchmark(dtw(cxdist)$distance, dtw(var1,var2)$distance, order="relative")[,1:4]
#                       test replications elapsed relative
# 1     dtw(cxdist)$distance          100   0.476    1.000
# 2 dtw(var1, var2)$distance          100   0.736    1.546
```

Also, if you're interested only in `$distance` you can pass `distance.only=T` to `dtw()` - it gives some speed-up.

Comment: Thanks very nice answer, very clear. I didn't know about Rcpp. Do you have any idea to speed up the process if I want to apply this on a lot of samples?

Comment: @WAF Thank you. One note: if you're interested only in `$distance` you can pass `distance.only=T` to `dtw()` - it gives some speed-up. As for applying code on lots of samples. It seems that `dtw()` uses only one core, so running the processing in a batch on multicore system or a cluster can potentially give benefits. Take a look at `foreach` package.